# read yml file from bash and store it into variables

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to read the following yml file and structure it into 3 variables in bash ?

```
services:
  app: mysql
   port:
   service: mysql
  app: mongo_instance
   port:
   service: mongo
  app: restful_api
   port: 5000
   service: api
```

Structure I need:

```
apps_order=("mysql" "restful_api" "mongo_instance")
ports=("" "5000" "")
service=("mysql" "api" "mongo")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Why would you do this in bash?

Comment: Your YAML file is invalid. The specification states that keys within a mapping need to be unique. But maybe yml is not the same a YAML..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK given the clarification about the YAML data, we can parse it. YAML is in that set of data formats with XML and JSON and CSV, where you really need to use a proper parser. I'm going to use Ruby (which ships with a YAML library) to read the file and output bash code. The shell will source that output to create the shell arrays.

```
$ source <(
    ruby -e '
        require "yaml"
        result = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Array.new}
        data = YAML.load_file(ARGV.shift)
        data["services"].each do |obj|
            obj.keys.each {|k| result[k] << obj[k]}
        end
        result.each_pair do |k,v|
            printf "%ss=(%s)\n", k, v.map {|e| "\"#{e}\""}.join(" ")
        end
    ' file.yaml
)

$ declare -p apps ports services
declare -a apps=([0]="mysql" [1]="mongo_instance" [2]="restful_api")
declare -a ports=([0]="" [1]="" [2]="5000")
declare -a services=([0]="mysql" [1]="mongo" [2]="api")
```

Comment: @gleen jackman. Many thanks. Just one questions what if i have more in the array.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean if there's more than "app","port","service" in the YAML?

Answer (score 0):

(not an answer, but a formatted comment)

Should your YAML look like this? "services" mapped to 3 objects

```
services:
- app: mysql
  port: ''
  service: mysql
- app: mongo_instance
  port: ''
  service: mongo
- app: restful_api
  port: 5000
  service: api
```

Comment: Yes that be more better ... like an array i believe